# How to interprete logistic regresion using Eviews having dummy variables

Tags: logistic, interpretation, categorical-encoding, z-test, eviews

I need your help with logistic regression analysis. My dependent variable is a dummy variable: 0 fails 1 successful.

Method: ML - Binary Logit  (Newton-Raphson / Marquardt steps)
variables and coefficient are
c=             -1.380208
comment =      -6.36E-05
updates=        0.291811
category=      -0.017782
obs with Dep : 0=    109 557
1=     76 658
My category is 13 that I also code in dummy variables and consider as control variables.
others element are good, p-value , z statistic , McFadden R-squared ...

Now is how to interpret and know which variables improve success and which one reduce success.